# PYTHON Canvas function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a problem with this code. Everything should be working well, but the songs aren't playing when I click on the Pauseplay button/canvas. Can someone please help me with this? When I click on the Pauseplay button, the function is supposed to play the song we previously selected by the Radiobutton.

```
from tkinter import*
from pygame.locals import*
import pygame.mixer

# CREATION FENETRE
fen=Tk()
fen.geometry("700x500")
fen.title("Lecteur MP3")
fen.configure(bg="#EBF5FC",highlightthickness=0)

def Play(self):
    """Fonction permettant de lancer une chanson à partir de la bibliotheque"""
    global joue
    nomFichier=value.get()
    print(nomFichier)
    if Pauseplay["text"] == "Play" and joue==0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(nomFichier)
        Pauseplay["text"] = "Pause"
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        joue=1
    elif Pauseplay["text"] == "Pause" and joue==1:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        joue=2
        Pauseplay["text"] = "Play"
    elif Pauseplay["text"]=="Play" and joue==2:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        joue=1

# ZONE DE LECTURE
Lect=Canvas(fen,width=500,height=400,bg="#FFFFFF",highlightthickness=0)
Lect.place(x=0,y=0)

# BOUTON PLAY/PAUSE
Pauseplay = Canvas(fen,bg="#EBF5FC",highlightthickness=0)
Pauseplay.create_oval(2, 2, 40, 40, fill='white')
Pauseplay.create_text(21,20,text='Play')
Pauseplay.tag_bind(Pauseplay,"<Button-1>", lambda self: Play(self))
Pauseplay.place(x=178, y=440, width=100, height=100)

# BASE DE DONNEES
value=StringVar()
C1=Radiobutton(fen,text="Sleep Away",variable=value,value="Sleep_Away.wav")
C2=Radiobutton(fen,text="Kalimba",variable=value,value="Kalimba.wav")
C3=Radiobutton(fen,text="Up Away",variable=value,value="Up_Away.wav")
C1.place(x=500,y=30)
C2.place(x=500,y=60)
C3.place(x=500,y=90)
joue=0

pygame.mixer.init()
fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, what actually happens when you run this?  One problem I see is that ``Pauseplay["text"]`` isn't going to work: a Canvas has no such property.  This looks like something intended for a Button, to see what state it is in; your global ``joue`` variable seems to be doing that job instead.

Comment: My window opens, with the button Play and the three Radiobuttons for the songs. I click on a Radiobutton and click on the Play button, but nothing happens... 
Thank you for your answer, I'll try to figure it out!